# How to show the Kibana dashboard to others as read only mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kibana, elk

I just created a dashboard as default workspace, and Whenever I tried to share the dashboard link and It let others to Edit and make the changes in the data. So, I don't want to do that I just want to let others only view the dashboard (Read-Only). Instead of editing and changing the existing data.

**Sample Dashboard (Erased some confidential things):**

[image]

I'm using the below image to host this Kibana dashboard:

**docker-elk**

**Kibana version**

> Version: 6.6.0

I just want to share the dashboard to others as read only users. How can I able to achieve this?

Comment: Whats the version of kibana. Is it 6.8 or 7.0+? Security features are free in these version where you can create read only user and provide read only access to kibana

Comment: You can't do that in 6.6 Kibana free version.

Comment: But in that article they mentioned that it supports from 6.x   https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-dashboard-only-mode

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan You need the security features to do that, on version 6.6 this is a paid feature, but since version 6.8 and 7.1 the basic security features are included in the basic license, which is free. You will need to upgrade your stack and configure the security.